# How does raw IQ change over the lifespan at the group-level?

Tags: intelligence, developmental-psychology, aging, iq

In the classic review of intelligence research (*[Intelligence: Knowns and Unknowns](http://www.psych.uiuc.edu/~broberts/Neisser%20et%20al,%201996,%20intelligence.pdf)*), Neisser et al (1996) write the following

> **Stability**. Intelligence test scores are fairly stable during
>   development. When Jones and Bayley (1941) tested a sample of children
>   annually throughout childhood and adolescence, for example, scores
>   obtained at age 18 were correlated r = .77 with scores that had been
>   obtained at age 6 and r = .89 with scores from age 12. When scores
>   were averaged across several successive tests to remove short-term
>   fluctuations, the correlations were even higher. The mean for ages 17
>   and 18 was correlated r = .86 with the mean for ages 5, 6, and 7, and
>   r = .96 with the mean for ages 11, 12, and 13. (For comparable
>   findings in a more recent study, see Moffitt, Caspi, Harkness, &
>   Silva, 1993.) Nevertheless, IQ scores do change over time. In the same
>   study (Jones & Bayley, 1941), the average change between age 12 and
>   age 17 was 7.1 IQ points; some individuals changed as much as 18
>   points.

Typically, IQ scores are standardised for age and thus remove age related differences.

My question is

**What is the  relationship between age and raw intelligence test score at the group-level from around age 5 and into adultyhood?**

From what I've read, I understand that at the group-level intelligence increases monotonically with age during childhood and that it levels-off at some point (perhaps around 18?). Also, below a certain age (e.g., in infancy), completely different tests are required to measured intelligence. I also understand that individuals may experience various trajectories (e.g., some might plateau earlier, etc.), but I'm interested in the group-level. Thus, an ideal answer would probably provide a sense of the functional form of the increase in intelligence over childhood and adolescence.

My first thought for an answer was to look at the test manual for a standardised child intelligence test, such as the [WISC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wechsler_Intelligence_Scale_for_Children), but I don't currently have easy access to that.

#### References

- Jones, H. E., and Bayley, N. (1941). The Berkeley Growth Study. Child
  Development, 12, 167-173.
- Moffitt, T. E., Gabrielli, W. F., Mednick, S. A., & Schulsinger, E (1981).
  Socioeconomic status, IQ, and delinquency. Journal of Abnormal
  Psychology, 90, 152-156.
- Neisser, U., Boodoo, G., Bouchard, T. J., Boykin, A. W., Brody, N.,
  Ceci, S. J., Halpern, D. F., Loehlin, J. C., Perloff, R., Sternberg, R.
  J., and Urbina, S. (1996). Intelligence: Knowns and unknowns. American
  Psychologist, 51:77-101. [FREE PDF](http://www.gifted.uconn.edu/siegle/research/Correlation/Intelligence.pdf)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, the introduction section of McArdle et al (2002) provides a good literature review on the topic (see link to PDF in references).

#### Early research by Jones and Conrad (1933)

McArdle et al (2002) extract a quote from Jones and Conrad's (1933) summary of the literature based on large cross-sectional studies and also the classic Army alpha tests:

> "The chief characteristic of the curve may be summarized as involving
>   a linear growth to about 16 years, and a negative acceleration beyond
>   16 to a peak between the ages of 18 and 21. A decline follows,
>   which is much more gradual than the curve of growth, but which by
>   the age of 55 involves a recession to the 14-year level. (p. 239)"

#### Cattell on Crystalised and Fluid Intelligence

Also, see Figure 1 in McArdle et al (2002) which extracts a diagram from Cattell (1987) that shows Cattell's theorised relationship between age and two types of intelligence, [crystalised and fluid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluid_and_crystallized_intelligence). The theory suggests that fluid intelligence increases at a faster rate and peaks at around 18 and then shows a steady decline, whereas crystalised intelligence increases throughout the life span, with the rate of learning decreasing over time, and arguably approaching a plateau around 50 before commencing a very gradual decline around 60.

#### References

- Cattell, R. B. (1987). Intelligence: Its structure, growth and action. Amsterdam: North-Holland.
- Jones, H. E., & Conrad, H. S. (1933). The growth and decline of intelli-
  gence: A study of a homogeneous group between the ages of ten and
  sixty. Genetic Psychology Monographs, 13(1), 223–275
- McArdle, J., Ferrer-Caja, E., Hamagami, F., and Woodcock, R. (2002).
  Comparative longitudinal structural analyses of the growth and decline
  of multiple intellectual abilities over the life span. Developmental
  Psychology, 38(1):115.
  [FREE PDF](http://www.iapsych.com/wj3ewok/LinkedDocuments/McArdle2002.pdf)

*NOTE: After posting the question, I did a little research and found the above research. I've self-awarded the answer for sake of closure, but I'm happy to award to someone else with a better answer.*